# Hide closing statements for algorithms

Tags: algorithms

I would like to generate an algorithm with the `algorithmic` package which does not show the annoying closing statements when I typeset it.  I have done this before but have now forgotten how to do it. Specifically,

```
   \FORALL Natural numbers N
      \STATE N=N-1 !
   \ENDFOR
```

I'd prefer that the final `\ENDFOR` statement not show up after typesetting as this just needlessly chews up space.

Comment: Can you post your answer as an answer to this question, so that you can accept it and the question be resolved?

Comment: It doesn't look like blackkettle will returen. So I added a CW answer. Could someone please upvote it once, so that this question gets off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 15):

From the `algorithmic` manual:

> There is a single option, `noend` that
>   may be invoked when the `algorithmic`
>   package is loaded. With this option
>   invoked the end statements are omitted
>   in the output. This allows space to be
>   saved in the output document when this
>   is an issue.

So, if you load the package with

```
\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}
```

there won't be any closing statements.

Comment: I use `\begin{algorithm}` around `algorithmic` and only load `\usepackage{algorithm}`. I get errors if a additionally `\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}`. Is there another way to remove the closing statements?

Comment: @CGFoX use `[noend]` argument with package `algpseudocode` instead of package `algorithmic`.

Answer (score 1):

Package `algpseudocode` also has a `noend` option.  It is invoked via:

`\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}`

This alternate approach solves the issue reported in a previous comment that adding package `algorithmic` to the document leads to the error:

`Command \algorithmic already defined. {\end{list}}`