# Pseudocode in Latex without ending if and for

Tags: formatting, algorithms

Is there such a package where the ending of a for loop or an if statement is **not** displayed? I don't mind for the LaTeX code itself, but for the result.

For example, I am using this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\newcommand{\algorithmicinput}{\textbf{input}}
\newcommand{\INPUT}{\item[\algorithmicinput]}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Dolphinn: Preprocessing (data structure)}
    \label{DolphinnPrep}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \INPUT{Parameter $d'$.}
    \STATE Initialize empty hashtable $T$.
    \FOR{$i = 1$ to $d'$}
        \STATE Sample $h_i \in F$ u.a.r.
        \FOR{each $x \in h_i(P)$}
            \STATE{Flip a fair coin and assign the result to $f_i(x)$.}
        \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR
    \STATE{For all $p \in P$, $f(p)=(f_1(h_1(p)), \ldots, f_{d'}(h_{d'}(p)))$.}
    \STATE{For all $p \in P$, add $p$ to the bucket of $T$ with key f(p)$.}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

Notice the "end for" lines. I want to get rid of them. How?

<sub>Same behavior is desired for the if statements.</sub>

Comment: Please post what you've got so far.

Comment: @TeXnician updated.

Comment: @gsamaras: Can you turn your code snippet into a minimal example?

Comment: @Werner updated, is that ok? If not let me know please.

Comment: @gsamaras: Not really. I modified the code to make it a minimal example that we can compile. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\usepackage[noend]{algorithmic}` Its a duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10533/124842 and here you can see a MWE guide: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: That would wok too @Bobyandbob, thanks! Werner ok I will have it in mind next time! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms), use [`algcompatible`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) with the `noend` package option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\MM}{\mathcal{M}}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algcompatible}
\newcommand{\algorithmicinput}{\textbf{input}}
\newcommand{\INPUT}{\item[\algorithmicinput]}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Dolphinn: Preprocessing (data structure)}
  \label{DolphinnPrep}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \INPUT{Metric $(\MM, d_{\MM})$, approximation factor $c>1$, LSH family $F=F(c,r)$, data set $P \subset \MM$, parameter $d'$.}
    \STATE Initialize empty hashtable $T$.
    \FOR{$i = 1$ to $d'$}
      \STATE Sample $h_i \in F$ u.a.r.
      \FOR{each $x \in h_i(P)$}
        \STATE{Flip a fair coin and assign the result to $f_i(x)$.}
      \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR
    \STATE{For all $p \in P$, $f(p)=(f_1(h_1(p)), \ldots, f_{d'}(h_{d'}(p)))$.}
    \STATE{For all $p \in P$, add $p$ to the bucket of $T$ with key $f(p)$.}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```